# Calculate minimum sample data $n$ for CI?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

I have this homework exercise which I don't know how to solve. Here is the problem (the translation may not correct): Before the election day, in order to know the percentage $p$ of voters who don't know who to vote yet, a team asked opinion of $n$ randomly selected voters. Calculate the minimum $n$ in order that the confidence interval $95\%$ has length below $0.04$.

According to my textbook, the formula to calculate $n$ is:

$$n\ge(\frac{\sigma u_\beta}{\epsilon})^2$$

Here is what I have done so far: the confidence level is $95\%$ so $u_\beta=1.96$.

The answer is $n=2401$ but I don't know how to solve it.
[image]

According to the formula above, I guess that $\epsilon=0.04$ but how do I calculate $\sigma=1$?

Comment: This is explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298355.  In particular, it shows you do *not* estimate $\sigma=1.$ (That's a mathematical impossibility.)  You estimate $\sigma=1/4$ because that's the worst possible case, which is necessarily for finding the  $n$ that is guaranteed to work *no matter what the responses might be.*

Comment: @whuber so if $\sigma=1/4$, how to know that $\epsilon=0.01$?

Comment: There's little to be learned by plugging numbers into formulas.  Instead, work out the solution from general principles: namely, the definition of a confidence interval and the formula for a Normal confidence interval.  The rest is just algebra.